# Node.js protobuf includes

Tags: node.js, protocol-buffers, protoc, protobuf.js

We are trying to implement a grpc service in Node.

We have a `common.proto`-file where we describe common messages, that we can reuse across different services.
Up until now, we have only implemented services in Go, and consumed them in either Go or PHP. This all works fine.

Now that we want to implement one service in Node, we have generated the pb.js-files, both from `common.proto`, and lets call it `service.proto`.

The problem is, that in `service_pb.js` it generates the following code: `require("../common_pb.js")`

This is of course not valid, as the path to `common_pb.js` is `node_modules/@company/common-node/common_pb.js`, while now it looks for it in `node_modules/@company/common-node/common_pb.js`.

I still have not been able to figure out how we can make this work correctly for Node, so if anyone has a solution that would be great.

Comment: What is the directory structure that contains the .proto files? What do the "import" lines in the .proto files look like? What command are you using to generate the files? What is the difference between the path where `common_pb.js` is, and where the other file is looking for it?

Comment: Did you ever happen to figure this out?

Comment: @AndresCastro
Yes, we did figure it out. It all had to do with the `-i` parameter. I'll add an answer that explains it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is what we came up with as a solution:

The tree of the project looks like this:

```
root/
├─ common/
│  ├─ common.proto
├─ some-service/
│  ├─ some-service.proto
├─ other-service/
│  ├─ other-service.proto
```

If we in `some-service.proto` needed a message definition from `common.proto` we had `import "common.proto";` and when running the project we included the common dir.

We changed this, so that we in the `some-service.proto` file wrote `common/common.proto`, and when running `protoc` just included `.` which is the root dir as shown in the tree above. That way the includes came out as `require('../common/common_pb.js');` instead of `require('../common_pb.js');`.